# Social login for REST API without FE

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth2

Всем привет,
давайте представим, что есть какой-то сервер, который по описанным api отдает какие-то данные, т.е rest. 
И какое-то количество клиентов (сайт/мобильное приложение), которые по этим api получают данные и отрисовывают что-то.

Для доступа к некоторым апи такого сервиса необходимо быть авторизованным в системе, поэтому появилась необходимость забацать авторизацию через популярные сервисы (social login) а-ля VK/Facebook/Google/Twitch, чтобы не бесить пользователей очередным вводом кредов и возней с их обработкой.
Но, возникла проблема, точнее непонимание того, как это все должно происходить на нашем простом restfull сервере, где нет привязки к какому-то клиенту и вообще статики как таковой.

Т.е если бы это было веб приложение, мы бы просто редиректнули пользователя на страничку с подтверждением выдачи определеных прав к ресурсному серверу (VK/Facebook/Google/Twitch), 
потом получили бы токен от этого сервера, сопоставили полученный аккаунт с системным, выплюнули бы домашнюю страничку и жили не тужили, но вот в нашем случае так не прокатит.

Собственно по этому и возникает вопрос а как же это сделать, где перехватывать логин запрос, что отдавать и как дать понять клиентской части, что мы молодцы и теперь этот аноним стал Васей из второго подъезда?

Все примеры и теорию, которые я изучил, справедливы для полноценного веб приложения, где фронт и бэк неразрывно связаны, но не для нашего случая :(

Вариант с авторизацией на клиенте, отправкой каких-то данных на сервер, на основе которых генерируется JWT токен, по которому потом будет проходить общение не подходит.

Comment: Я бы мог, наверное, написать вам ответ, однако совершенно не ясно что такое `FE` из заголовка. Пока что могу лишь сказать, что из ваших слов неясна заявленная специфичность и должны работать стандартные подходы реализации аутентификации и авторизации.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб здравствуйте, FE  - frontend